# In the "Dexter" episode "Road Kill" what do the Korean couple say when they break in?

Tags: translation, dexter

At around time 17:00 Dexter (as Kyle Butler) and Arthur Mitchel (the Trinity Killer) break into Arthur's childhood home. A Korean couple live the home and discuss something when they walk in. What do they say?

Comment: I don't see how asking for a dialogue translation is trivia. The only way to know whether what they say is unimportant or not is to provide the translation that OP is looking for in the first place.

Comment: If the dialogue was important, it would have been translated to begin with...At most there could be an easter egg of some kind...but this is generally unanswerable unless one speaks Korean....I would deem this difficult to answer..but I'm not aware of how many korean speakers there are active at movies.se

Comment: According to iPhone, the first thing the man says is "I'm not sure about now" (when Trinity forces his way in), but then, both the husband and wife are talking and iOS is lost... You should ask Masuka, the actor has Korean roots :-) Btw it's from about 33:00 not 17:00...